# Creating and Exporting Certificate for Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7

Tags: certificate, remote-desktop

Can anyone help me create a certificate to use with the new version of Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7? I see the new version removed the "Store as plain text" option, but added using a certificate to the list.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a certificate (self-signed or whatever) that I could install on both computers to allow me to pass the config file between machines. I haven't been able to find anything online!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you in Remote Desktop Connection Manager click on the Help menu, and Usage, you will see a web page. On the Contents list, click on Encryption Settings (Under Local Options). There you will see how to create a personal certificate that RDCMan can use.

You will first need to get makecert.exe if you don't have it on your computer. You can get it by installing Windows SDK or Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. For others, I found makecert.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64